# Formula of Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to make a formula to my calculated column :

If the DD Rating is High => Add 3 months to the [DD Sign-off Date]
If the DD Rating is Medium=> Add 6 months to the [DD Sign-off Date]
If the DD Rating is Low => Add 12 months to the [DD Sign-off Date]

So the formula must be like this :

```
  =IF([DD Rating]="High",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+3,DAY([DD Sign-off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy")),
   IF([DD Rating]="Medium",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+6,DAY([DD Sign-off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy")),
   IF([DD Rating]="Low",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+12,DAY([DD Sign-off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Comment: So what is the problem with this formula? are you getting an error whilw saving this formula?

Comment: Yes when i save I get an error: Sorry, something went wrong

Comment: Is `DD Sign-off Date` is required column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All example formulas in [this topic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)) use commas "," as the parameter delimiter character. In some countries, the comma is reserved for use as the decimal mark. In such countries, users creating a calculated field must use semi-colons ";" as the delimiter character.

Try using:

```
=IF([DD Rating]="High";
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]);MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+3;DAY([DD Sign-off Date]));"dd/mm/yyyy");
   IF([DD Rating]="Medium";
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]);MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+6;DAY([DD Sign-off Date]));"dd/mm/yyyy");
   IF([DD Rating]="Low";
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]);MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+12;DAY([DD Sign-off Date]));"dd/mm/yyyy"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below Formula:

```
=IF([DD Rating]="High",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+3,DAY([DD Sign- off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy"),
   IF([DD Rating]="Medium",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+6,DAY([DD Sign-off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy"),
   IF([DD Rating]="Low",
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([DD Sign-off Date]),MONTH([DD Sign-off Date])+12,DAY([DD Sign-off Date])),"dd/mm/yyyy"))))
```

Comment: Same Problem :(

Comment: Strange. I tried this and it is working on my site. make sure you are returning your calculated column as "Single line of text"(option given below formula) and `DD Sign-off Date` is date and time field.